# Modern standard texts on distributed systems

Tags: reference-request, distributed-systems

I'm starting a job soon that involves a large number of disciplines interacting at once. I'm knowledgeable in most of these areas; at least enough that when I don't know something I know how to look it up. There is however an element of distributed computing involved in my new job and I don't think I'm as prepared for this. I've heard of a lot of the problems in this area, and know some basic techniques around them but I think my foundations are quite poor right now. I'm looking for foundational and standard texts in distributed computing. Ideally I'd like to be able to walk away after having read a book with a strong theoretical foundation and then I'd also like something with a bit more of a practical focus if it exists. My primary goal above all others is to get to a place where I can easily look things up, search for previous solutions, and ask experts intelligent questions. What books/papers would you recommend I read? Although I'm still interested in broader references, if it helps focus answers I'm particularly interested in distributed caching.

I'd also like to emphasize that I'm looking for a modern answer to this. I've found people on this very site asking this question but the answers are from 10 years ago. This feels like a very long time in this field. I'm not rejecting older answers to the question, but I would like the confidence that those references are still the gold standard today before investing a huge amount of time into them.

Comment: You did not specify the exact topics... Also,, some books just never age, so " answers from 10 years ago. " may still be valid for most cases. If you want theory go for books written by theorists. nancy lynch distributed algorithms,  Petr Kuznetsov Algorithms for concurrent systems,  The Art of Multiprocessor Programming and  J. welch distributed computing fundamentals simulations and advanced topics. I didn't hear of more recent books that are theory-focused. The most recent here is Kuznetsov's book from 2018 and it is very accessible btw. He also has nice things on his personal webpage

Comment: Like I said I'll still read older books as long as they're still the best reads! I'll take a look at all 4 and see if I can narrow it down to 2 from there. Thanks!